# git repository stopped work

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a git repository that have worked normally. It's on a server and me and 3 friends ssh to this server to work on this repository, each with your own user (but the repository was created with a different user).

So, now, it simply doesn't work anymore.

When we try to run a

```
git status
```

we have the follow message

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

But, if we run

```
sudo git status
```

it works normally.

So, I think that I have i simple problem with the permissions, but I had checked and everything seems OK.

Maybe, I should make something to tells git that this repository is shared (cause we are 4 people working on the same repository), but I don't know how to make it.

Comment: Great, you just solved your own question, your GIT directory/configuration files have bad permissions, which don't allow non-root users access to them, while root users do have access to them.

Comment: git is a **distributed** VCS. Why are you all working in the same copy of the repo?

Comment: @nethaus, but the permissions of the .git directory and all the files inside it are OK. Do you have any sugestion? Tks

Comment: @Wooble, we are making it cause we don't wanna copy the whole project to diferents machines (it's big...). There are problems in do it? Tks

Comment: "Too big to clone" is quite possibly a case of putting assets that don't belong in version control in the repo. In my opinion you can work the way you are, but you're giving up a lot of the great features git was created for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow you broke the permissions of your `.git` directory.

In a shell, look at the permissions:

```
ls -la
# example
drwxr-xr-x 8 some_user some_group 4.0K Apr 1 13:37 .git
```

Something on your platform should be fishy. `some_user` might be `root`, so may be `some_group`. You can change the owner of the directory to your user:

```
chown -R $USER .git
```

Change the group:

```
chgrp -R users .git
```

And the permissions:

```
chmod -R u=rwx .git // owner gets read, write, execute permissions
chmod -R g=rx // group gets read, write,
chmod -R o=x  // others get just execute
```

Comment: I made 'chmod -R g=rwx' instead of 'g=rx' and it worked.
But it's strange... Why it stopped to work? Before today, it worked fine. I think that it can arrive again.

Comment: @VitorLima Did you execute any operation with `sudo` that changed ownership? Did you clone the repository using `sudo`? All this could have caused this.

Comment: I did not clone with sudo. Maybe I could do some operation as a super user, I'm thinking about.  But, anyway, thank you for helping me.